# this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function in ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I created a library according to the official documentation, but there was an error when I registered the event listener. There is no problem on Android, it only happens on ios. I did a lot of research but I don't know how to solve it. What is the reason for this?

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from "react-native";

const TimJSModule = NativeModules.TimJs;

export class ExampleClass {
    private manager: String = "sdkManager";
    private nativeModule: any;
    // private logEmitterSubscription?: EmitterSubscription;

    constructor(module: any) {
        this.nativeModule = module;
        this.addListener();
    }

    private addListener() {
        const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(TimJSModule);
        this.addLogListener(eventEmitter);
        this.addSDKListener(eventEmitter);
    }

    private addLogListener(eventEmitter: NativeEventEmitter) {
        eventEmitter.addListener('logFromNative', (data: any) => {
            const { logs } = data;
            console.log("======log from native module======", logs);
        });
    }

    private addSDKListener(eventEmitter: NativeEventEmitter) {
        eventEmitter.addListener('sdkListener', (response: any) => {
            
        });
    }
}
```

This is the key code, and An error is reported when instantiated. `this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function`.

And i also checked the prototype chain in `nativeModule`, not found `addListener` function.

Any one know what's happen?

I used `create-react-native-library` package to create library.